# Python won't run my project- anyone want to check over my code?

Tags: python, project

Starting on my first project, a calculator which solves different math problems. At this stage it only does Pythagora's theorem (it has options to calculate the hypotenuse or another side). There is also an option to convert temperatures, though the actual code isn't implemented yet.
I try to run the code with the latest version of python and it does that thing where it opens for a split second and then closes. I know this means something in the code is wrong. Because I'm new to this, I get things wrong a lot and I'm having trouble finding my mistakes.
This is my code if anyone wants to read it. Feedback is appreciated and I'm happy to answer any questions.

```
option = input("1. Pythagora's Theorem 2. Tempurature Conversions")
option = int(option)
if option == 1:
 op = input("1. Calculate the length of the hypotenuse 2. Calculate the length of another side")
 op = int(op)
  if op == 1:
   a = input("Enter the length of side a: ")
   b = input("Enter the length of side b: ")
   a = int(a)
   b = int(b)
   c = a*a + b*b
   print(c)
   print ("Answer is in surd form.")
  if option == 2:
   a = input("Enter the length of side a: ")
   hyp = input("Enter the length of the hypotenuse: ")
   a = int(a)
   hyp = int(hyp)
   b = hyp*hyp - a*a
   print(b)
   print("Answer is in surd form.")
  else:
   print("That is not a valid option. Enter a valid option number.")
else: ("That is not a valid option. Eneter a valid option number.")
```

Edit: It is fixed, problem was a missing ")" and probably my weird indentation. It all works fine now, thanks for all the help, it makes learning this much easier!

Comment: Python script should be running in terminal. Did you run the command such as "python <your_script_name>" in the terminal?

Comment: Note that we expect you to identify a *specific problem* with your code, and reduce it to the shortest [mre] that produces that specific problem when run without changes, **before** asking a question here. If you're asking someone else to try to find the problem, there's more to do before asking. See also http://sscce.org/

Comment: White spaces (indents) **matters** in Python. Get it right. Your `if`s aren't indent-ed correctly. Also, you last print is missing... a `print`. And should be on a new line. There are more issues, but you'll manage it when it finally runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python interpreter should actually give you feedback. Run python directly from a terminal so that your program doesn't close.

Here's a fixed version of your code which works:

```
option = input("1. Pythagora's Theorem 2. Tempurature Conversions")
option = int(option)
if option == 1:
    op = input("1. Calculate the length of the hypotenuse 2. Calculate the length of another side")
    op = int(op)
    if op == 1:
        a = input("Enter the length of side a: ")
        b = input("Enter the length of side b: ")
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        c = a*a + b*b
        print(c)
        print ("Answer is in surd form.")
    elif op == 2:
        a = input("Enter the length of side a: ")
        hyp = input("Enter the length of the hypotenuse: ")
        a = int(a)
        hyp = int(hyp)
        b = hyp*hyp - a*a
        print(b)
        print("Answer is in surd form.")
    else:
        print("That is not a valid option number.")
```

Please note that most programmers use 4 spaces to indent code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a ")" on line

```
a = input("Enter the length of side a: "
```

Comment: Yes, just fixed it, thanks. Still doesn't work though, but it helps.

Comment: And the redundant "```" near the end there which I assume is an artifact left over from copying the code from somewhere. The code should run after you removed it.

Comment: You will find that forgetting a closing parentheses is one of the most common sorts of programing errors that we do. When this happens, the compiler will report an error on line such and such, but that is the line where the compiler realized that a closing parentheses was missing. The actual error is with the line before. So a handy tip is that anytime you get an error on a given line and the line looks just fine, check the line before. You may have forgotten a closing parentheses, or something of that nature.

Comment: The "```" was from putting it on here, thought I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

You havent followed proper indentations, and you have made one logical mistake

```
option = input("1. Pythagora's Theorem 2. Tempurature Conversions > ")
option = int(option)
if option == 1:
    op = input("1. Calculate the length of the hypotenuse 2. Calculate the length of another side > ")
    op = int(op)
    if op == 1:
        a = input("Enter the length of side a: ")
        b = input("Enter the length of side b: ")
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        c = a*a + b*b
        print(c)
        print ("Answer is in surd form.")
    elif op == 2:
        a = input("Enter the length of side a: ")
        hyp = input("Enter the length of the hypotenuse: ")
        a = int(a)
        hyp = int(hyp)
        b = hyp*hyp - a*a
        print(b)
        print("Answer is in surd form.")
    else:
        print("That is not a valid option. Enter a valid option number.")
elif option == 2:
    print("You havent programmed it")
else:
    print("That is not a valid option. Eneter a valid option number.")
```